# Sort a file from the root

Tags: php

I'm using this code

```
$sort_data = get_sort('data/profiles/name.cms','¦');
```

The required "Data" folder is in the root of my host, but the php file that calling name.cms is in sub folder : styles/default/pages/left_member.php

and I'm failing to get that data from the name.cms file, any idea how to call the file from the root?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute (`/path/to/data/profiles/name.cms`), rather than relative path?

Comment: Yes, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the PHP `$_SERVER` functionality and target the root directory.

**Example:**

```
$sort_data = get_sort($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/data/profiles/name.cms','¦');
```

It's important to note that what's actually defined as the root directory is defined in your configuration file.

> *'DOCUMENT_ROOT' - "The document root directory under which the current*
> *script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file."*

Source [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

**UPDATE AS PER YOUR COMMENT:**

> Thank you for your help, I already tried it but it's getting whole
> xampp directory, so it didn't work.

If you ever take your project *"live"*, the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` functionality should work. The reason why it doesn't work for you right now, is because you have a *"project structure"* in your `root` directory. I.e. `localhost/myproject/index.php`. What you meant by `root` is actually the project folder and not the *actual* `root` folder.

In that case, you can try 3 different options.

1. An absolute path without using the PHP reserved variable `$_SERVER`
   to find it.

**Example:**

```
$sort_data = get_sort('/data/profiles/name.cms','¦');
```

2. Manually manipulate the directory path.

**Example:**

```
$sort_data = get_sort('../data/profiles/name.cms','¦');
```

You can add as many *"level up"*, i.e. `../`, as it takes to get to your desired starting point and then locate the folder.

3. Define your own *"root"* path variable.

Example:

```
$my_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myproject';
```

You can now use `$my_root` with your path, like so:

```
$sort_data = get_sort($my_root.'/data/profiles/name.cms','¦');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I already tried it but it's getting whole xampp directory, so it didn't work.

Comment: Then you're not going by root directory, but rather a project folder. i.e. *localhost/myproject/index.php*. If you ever go *"live"* with your project, the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will work. Alternatively, you could backtrace your pathing. `../` means one folder back in the directory. Keep doing that until you can enter your specified path.

Comment: See edited answer for clearification on possible solutions @IsaacSabir